typing.get_args(tuple[()]) differs from typing.get_args(typing.Tuple[()])
I have some code to check the types of tuple elements. For this I use the get_args() function from the module typing. Since typing.Tuple is deprecated since Python 3.9 I use builtins.tuple. I noticed that the outputs of get_args(Tuple[()]) and get_args(tuple[()]) differ up to Python 3.11.
Python 3.9.13
>>> typing.get_args(tuple[()])
()
>>> typing.get_args(tuple)
()
>>> typing.get_args(typing.Tuple[()])
((),)

Python 3.10.11
>>> typing.get_args(tuple[()])
()
>>> typing.get_args(tuple)
()
>>> typing.get_args(typing.Tuple[()])
((),)

Python 3.11.9
>>> typing.get_args(tuple[()])
()
>>> typing.get_args(tuple)
()
>>> typing.get_args(typing.Tuple[()])
()

Why was this changed and how can I check if the type is an empty tuple?
I looked for an answer in the documentation.
